# Once I update to firebase using angularfire2 my website freezes

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

i have a form that contains nine field. the user will fill these fields then he will click the save button.
the save button will take these informations transfrom them into an object and send them to my service where a specific function will check if this node do exists in firebase if it exists it will update. if not it will be created.
the problem is the first push of the button save will always work. but the second time my website freezes. im using angular2 and angularfire2.
sorry it basically entering an infinite loop which causes my website to freeze after the second click of the save button.

```
constructor(private db:UserInfoService) {
this.items =   
this.db.getData().subscribe(snapshot=>this.getAllData(snapshot.val()));

  }

getData(){

 return this.db.object('users/71933808',{ preserveSnapshot: true });

  }

savedata(path,userInfo){
this.db.object(`users/${path}/`,{ preserveSnapshot: true })
    .subscribe(snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.exists()) {
          this.addingUserInfo(userInfo);
        }else{

         this.updatingUserInfo(userInfo);
        }
    });
     }
```

in this method i am creating my object to pass it to savedata function:

```
loging(user,placeholder){
   placeholder = placeholder.replace(/\s/g, '');

   this.items[''+placeholder+'']=user;

   }
getAllData(item:any){
  this.items = item;
```

}

```
saveData(){

  this.db.savedata('71933808',this.items);

  }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your code. Thanks

Comment: the issue was with the .exists() function it was making the infinite loop i dont know what to do to check if the node exists or not.

Comment: Id it didn't exist, if(snapshot) { is enough. You don't need the .exist, It will return null

Comment: And the function addingUserInfo add something to firebase no?

Comment: yes it does add something

Answer (score 0):

I think that I get your problem!

you subscribe to

```
db.object('yourPath')
```

And in the subscription, you call *updatingUserInfo()* which modify the content of the 'yourPath' in Firebase.

So *db.object('yourPath')* will change its content. And will redo the subscription function and then *updatingUserInfo()*.

That's why you have an infinite loop.